# Shapley values where possible coalition size less than number of players

Tags: game-theory

Suppose I have a game in which $n$ players which can form coalitions of size $k < n$. I then have a characteristic function $v$ which assigns a worth to each of the $n^{k}$ possible $k$-player combinations. Assume further that the order of the players matters, e.g. the coalition {1,2,3} may not have the same worth as {2,1,3}.

Is it possible to calculate Shapley values for each player in this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

One approach I wondered is the following: Denote by $N = \lbrace 1, \cdots , n \rbrace$ the set of players and K the set of size $k$ coalitions made up from players in N in which order matters i.e $|K| = n^k$. Let $v:K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function.

For $S \subseteq K$, let $S_m$ denote the player in position m. Additionally, denote by $S[S_m = k]$ the original coalition S with the $m$-th player swapped for player $k \in N$.

Define the value assigned to player $i$ as

$$
 \phi_{i}(v) =  \frac{1}{C} \sum\limits_{m=1}^{3} \quad \sum\limits_{S \subseteq K \text{ : } S_m \quad \neq i} v(S[S_m = i]) - v(S)
$$
where $C$ is some appropriate normalization. Im not sure how to prove it satisfies the axioms or what C should be but intuitively I am averaging the effects of swapping players in a coalition with the player of interest. Could this be a fruitful avenue?

Comment: Just a couple of clarifying questions: First, are you saying that ONLY coalitions of size $k$ for some $k < n$ can form, or that ALL coalitions of size up to and including some $k < n$ can form? Second, when you say Shapley value, do you mean the solution should be linear, symmetric and efficient?

Comment: Yes, only coalitions of size $k$ for some $k<n$. And yes, I mean that it satisfies those axioms (plus the null player axiom).

Comment: I'm interested in this, but I still don't understand. In your next to last paragraph you propose assigning a worth of zero to coalitions of size greater than $k$. That would seem to imply that coalitions of size $\leq k$ could form and have nonzero worths, which contradicts what you wrote in your reply to me. Regardless, the difficulty in your model is making sense of the characteristic function. For example, with your assumptions there is no "grand coalition". There actually are $n$ grand coalitions, depending on how the players are ordered. Have you thought about things like that?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I suppose with my suggestion I was wondering whether the problem was equivalent to another problem formulation in which Shapley's original solution would hold. For example, in the machine learning literature it is common to "one-hot encode" categorical features, which turns a multi-class problem into a binary problem which can be tackled using binary classification etc. In truth I'm not sure how to tackle this problem, so your help is appreciated!

Comment: First, a correction: There would actually be $n!$ grand coalitions, one for each ordering of the players. There is an approach to the Shapley value that looks at it as an averaging process. You could create a characteristic function in that spirit: That is, for example, let the worth of a given coalition be the average of the worths over all orderings of the players. Not sure if that will make sense, would have to think about it. BTW, the Shapley value actually assigns a value to each player, although that will imply a value for each coalition by simply adding the individual worths.

Comment: What I want is a value assigned to each player $\lbrace 1, \cdots , n \rbrace$. What I essentially want is a method of deriving this value based on observing the worth of all possible coalitions of size $k$ (of which there are $n^k$).

Comment: Perhaps one can extend the Shapley value, but I can't see immediately how to do it. Look, what you essentially want here is a linear map from $R^{n^k}$ to $R^n$ (space of characteristic functions to space of agents) that is symmetric and efficient. Problem is what do you mean by efficiency? Remember, when order matters you have $n!$ grand coalitions. Best I can see you doing is arguing that all grand coalition worths are zero so you want a linear, symmetric map $\phi$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(i) = 0$. Probably more than one, but without further clarification, I can't see doing more.

Comment: There are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ordered $k$-player coalitions, not $n^k$.

Comment: One approach I wondered is the following: Denote by $N = \lbrace 1, \cdots , n \rbrace$ the set of players and K the set of size $k$ coalitions made up from players in N in which order matters i.e $|K| = n^k$. Let $v:K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function. 

For $S \subseteq K$, let $S_m$ denote the player in position m. Additionally, denote by $S[S_m = k]$ the original coalition S with the $m$-th player swapped for player $k \in N$. Continued below...

Comment: Define the value assigned to player $i$ as 

$$
 \phi_{i}(v) =  \frac{1}{C} \sum\limits_{m=1}^{3} \quad \sum\limits_{S \subseteq K \text{ : } S_m \quad \neq i} v(S[S_m = i]) - v(S)
$$
where $C$ is some appropriate normalization. Im not sure how to prove it satisfies the axioms or what C should be but intuitively I am averaging the effects of swapping players in a coalition with the player of interest. Could this be a fruitful avenue?

Comment: This still requires a lot of clarification; you haven't addressed some of the points raised by @user167131. a) Why do you propose to assign zero only to coalitions with $\gt k$ players, even though you say above that you only want to allow coalitions with exactly $k$ players? What value would you assign to smaller coalitions? b) What do you mean by each of the axioms? Except for linearity, it's not clear what they should mean in this context, since there's no such thing as adding or removing a player, and there's no grand coalition. Please spell out more explicitly what you're looking for.

Comment: a) I have addressed. That was a mistake on my part - I do not intend to consider coalitions larger or smaller than $k$ and so I am not proposing to assign zero to those coalitions. b) I realise I need to think more carefully about the axioms for this problem. Rather than adding or removing players, it is really about replacing players since coalitions must stay the same size. I think that Shapley like axioms can be rethought in this case.

Comment: I'd understand better what you're trying to do if you were trying to assign values to each player in a given coalition, such that the sum over all players in the coalition would yield the value of the coalition; that would be an analogue of efficiency: Dividing up the value of these restricted coalitions instead of dividing up the value of the grand coalition. But what does it mean to assign a value to each player for the entire characteristic function? What should these values add up to in the efficiency axiom? In your current proposal, they add up to $0$ by symmetry.

Comment: First, thanks to @joriki for the correction. There are $n!/(n-k)!k!$ coalitions of size $k$ (from $n$ players) and, if order matters, each one of those has $k!$ permutations, so the total is indeed $n!/(n-k)!k! \times k! = n!/(n-k)!$. I should have known that. Harry Booth, why don't you take a small example, say $n = 3, \; k=2$, construct a sample characteristic vector of dimension $n!/(n-k)! = 6$, then write out the value for player $i$ (this is how I usually work). This should be a good test of your thought processes and expose any problems in your logic.